# Remove characters from string based on user input

Tags: php

Suppose I have a string:

```
$str="1,3,6,4,0,5";
```

Now user inputs `3`.

I want that to remove `3` from the above string such that above string should become:

```
$str_mod="1,6,4,0,5";
```

Is there any function to do the above?

Comment: `str_replace()`? Thats a good start. Also `preg_replace()`

Comment: you can use first `explode` , `unset` , `implode` , `str_replace()` etc.  Read about them and use as per your requirement.

Comment: why users are upvoting this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can split it up, remove the one you want then whack it back together:

```
$str = "1,3,6,4,0,5";
$userInput = 3;

$bits = explode(',', $str);
$result = array_diff($bits, array($userInput));

echo implode(',', $result); // 1,6,4,0,5
```

Bonus: [Make `$userInput` an array at the definition](https://eval.in/314342) to take multiple values out.

Comment: That's actually pretty clever. +1

Answer (score 2):

```
preg_replace('/\d[\D*]/','','1,2,3,4,5,6');
```

in place of \d just place your digit [php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Comment: Regex is not needed in this situation

Comment: wrong its less lines, solves commo or no comma problem solves removing a whole 3 not a 3 from 33 . And exploding parsing then intersecting arrays must be more resource waste

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to do string manipulations, you can split the string into multiple pieces, remove the ones you don't need, and join the components back:

```
$numberToDelete = 3;
$arr = explode(',',$string);
while(($idx = array_search($numberToDelete, $components)) !== false) {
    unset($components[$idx]);
}
$string = implode(',', $components);
```

The above code will remove all occurrences of 3, if you want only the first one yo be removed you can replace the `while` by an `if`.